# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, iis, vb.net-2010

I had my project set up on a virtual machine and working fine.I am trying to set it up on another machine with same IIS settings. I am getting above error and not able to figure out why. I'm using VS 2010 and Sql server 2008 ( Remote). Since, it was working fine on VM various issues like enabling remote connections, port or sql service should not be there. I am using same web.config, so I assume connection string would be correct. I am also able to connect via Management studio. I have tried almost everything mentioned in other similar questions. Could anyone suggest what else could I try to fix it ?

Comment: please check your `connection string` or post here

Comment: It is same as I am using on VM and another server with no problems .

Comment: Can you ping the sql server from this new server?

Comment: Yes I can . And able to connect via Management studio as well.